# Why my color customized theme isn't working? (PC)

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

All I want is to change the colors of Chrome's interface (background and border, tabs, buttons, you name it). I tried installing a theme I found in store, then copied a portion of the code from manifest.json and edited the values.

My theme is without images, so the only file within the folder is manifest.json

I'm using Windows 7, so by default, Chrome is glossy.

I use the "Load unpacked extension..." button to test it, very few things such as one or two text colors were successfully changed, Chrome is still glossy.

Here's the json code

```
{
    "name": "Mystic Theme",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "theme": {
        "colors": {
            "bookmark_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
            "button_background": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "control_background": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "frame": [ 255, 96, 128 ],
            "frame_inactive": [ 0, 32, 64 ],
            "frame_incognito": [ 64, 96, 128 ],
            "frame_incognito_inactive": [ 32, 32, 64 ],
            "ntp_background": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "ntp_header": [ 209, 209, 209 ],
            "ntp_link": [ 0, 255, 255 ],
            "ntp_link_underline": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
            "ntp_section": [ 209, 209, 209 ],
            "ntp_section_link": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "ntp_section_link_underline": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "ntp_section_text": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
            "ntp_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
            "tab_background_text": [ 255, 0, 0 ],
            "tab_text": [ 255, 255, 255 ],
            "toolbar": [ 255, 0, 0 ]
        },
        "tints": {
            "background_tab": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
            "buttons": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
            "frame": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
            "frame_inactive": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
            "frame_incognito": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
            "frame_incognito_inactive": [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        }
    },
    "version": "0.0.0.1"
}
```

Why is Chrome ignoring my settings? What did I miss?

**Note**: I added "(PC)" at the end of the title so that it's not mistaken with another question which is related to Android customization.

Comment: where did you get the documentation for those extension manifest parameters? its cool that seems to work on some but I dont see those listed here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest and i dont see manifest version 3 like your example

Comment: @ZigMandel I copied it as reference from another theme. Also I tested removing it and Chrome for some reason demands it (also that the value must be greater than zero).

Comment: but its maybe a theme manifest and not an extension manifest format.

Comment: I did it according to [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes), and the [theme creation guide](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ThemeCreationGuide)

Comment: why manifest version 3? i can't find that in your links. try using version 2